# What's the RPi camera board called (internally)?

Tags: python, camera, raspicam

I connected a Rpi-camera board to the camera socket on my RPi (not a usb webcam). I have been searching the internet on how to call the camera in Python.
The camera works (`raspistill` and `raspivid` both work).

To be more specific, I'm using the [qr-tools](https://launchpad.net/qr-tools) library and I'm trying to use the `decode_webcam` function.

```
decode_webcam(self, callback=lambda s:None, device='/dev/video0')
```

When using `/dev/video0`, I get errors saying the device was not found. So what do I fill in after `device=`?

Thanks!

Comment: try ls /dev/
to get a look at what's in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are now a couple of V4L drivers for the Pi's camera module including an [official one](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=62364); using such a driver should cause the camera module to show up as `/dev/video0` (though you may find you need to fiddle with some settings using `v4l2-ctl`, as per the linked forum thread).

Answer (score 5):

It does not seem that the Pi Camera shows up as a standard Linux Video device (/dev/video0 or other).

However there is a python library that you can use to access the camera on the Pi via Python.

The Python library is called [picamera](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/picamera), and there is plenty of discussion on using it over at the [Raspberry Pi forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=56478).

I am not sure how this will work with the `decode_webcam` function you are trying to use though.

Comment: I already found that library and I've searched through it but it doesn't help me. Thanks anyway!