# RasPi Camera Board and Motion

Tags: camera, raspicam, motion, mmal, v4l2

I just got my Camera Board and a Model A Raspberry Pi to use as a security camera for my house.  I had been using Motion with a Logitech C170 USB camera on my Model B board and it worked great except for the quality. I was expecting the Raspberry Pi Camera Board to show up as `/dev/video0` but when I run Motion I get an error:

> Failed to open video device /dev/video0: No such file or directory

The camera works fine with `raspistill -d`.  This has to work with Motion as it has to take videos/pictures when movement is detected and I have to be able to access it from work.

[This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10033/whats-the-rpi-camera-board-called-internally) was no good for me as it never answered my question and I'm not using python.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can access the camera board on /dev/video0 by running the command:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

This will have to be run on every boot of the device.  Or you can put `modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` in /etc/rc.local to make it run on every boot automatically.

Comment: You can add the line to /etc/modules to get the kernel to insert the module on boot automatically. 
    <code> echo "bcm2835-v4l2" | tee -a /etc/modules </code>
Ensure you can run the command first
    <code> sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2 </code>

Comment: Note: it is an "L" not a "1" for bcm2835-v4l2.

Comment: why does this work ? what's the magic behind it.

Comment: is there any rationale behind it not being enabled automatically on every boot? Any clue why raspi-config doesn't do that when you enable the cam?

Answer (score 11):

to load the model after each reboot,  use this setting

1. **sudo nano /etc/modules**
2. enter **bcm2835-v4l2**
3. exist and save the fle
4. sudo reboot

Answer (score 5):

The standard motion dosn't work with the RPI camera. There is a variant called motion-mmal in development which works with the RPI camera

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=44966&p=379561#p374790 is a forum chat on setting it up

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/665518/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera this is a guide on using motion mmal to set up a security camera.

Comment: The standard motion works fine through v4l2 after loading module `bcm2835-v4l2`. Though probably not as good as with MMAL.

Answer (score 2):

to get motion to work(out of the box) you can install the [Userspace Video4Linux2](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=16)

It will create the /dev/video0 device node correctly on the Raspberry Pi.

I have just followed the [install instructions](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14) and not only does motion just work, the example(optional) [motion.conf](http://linux-projects.org/downloads/examples/motion.conf) sets up the Pi as a streaming server so that you can access it remotely in a browser.

the developer is asking for donations, I am definitely going to contribute.

Comment: Some dead links.

Answer (score 2):

(from https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/18214/12486)

You will be able to access to the raspi camera like other V4L2 device using :

- the [official kernel V4L2 driver bcm2835-v4l2](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62364)

> ```
> sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
> ```

- the [unofficial userspace V4L2 driver for the Raspberry Pi Camera Module](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14)

> `uv4l --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I tried this, it set up /dev/video0 OK but it did not work with motion:
http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=16

But then found this blog which seems to work:
http://rbnrpi.wordpress.com/project-list/setting-up-wireless-motion-detect-cam/

Note that the motion-mmal apparently only supports 3 resolutions right now: 352x288; 640x480 and 1024*576

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Today it was working, the next day it died.

tried a couple of the stuff here and other procedures found on google.

I eventually fixed it by activating the I2C protocol in raspi confing.(didn't think that was the problem since from what i know the camera uses the CSI-2 protocol and I never tweaked with it)

Answer (score -1):

I used motionpie https://github.com/ccrisan/motionPie to turn it into a IP cam.