# Streaming Video modprobe ERROR

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video

I'm attempting to get streaming video working.

One of the answers here: [RasPi Camera Board and Motion](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10480/raspi-camera-board-and-motion/26386#26386) suggested using the command `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`.

First I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

However, when I run this command on my RPi 3 Model B I get the following:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() 
could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.50-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I had the same issue.
I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459296/could-not-open-moddep-file-lib-modules-3-xx-generic-modules-dep-bin-when-mo) that the linux image should be reinstalled ( `#apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)`).

However, at the time this answer is written, the only images on the raspbian repo are 4.4.0, while `uname -r` returned 4.4.5 on my raspbian. Meanwhile, `ls /lib/modules/` contained 4.9.x dirs.

So I don't know what happened to the raspbian image, but installing rpi-update and then running it fixed the issue for me:

`sudo apt-get install rpi-update && sudo rpi-update`

If you need a specific kernel version, well, you gotta install it yourself.